# Urgent need of help splitting a JSON formatted string received by UDP

Tags: string, json

I guess that my problems are because I'm new to C, but after spending three evenings without success I thought I'd give it a try to ask here!

I receive a JSON-formatted string in a UDP message. It contains several values that I would like to catch and convert to variables. The string format is like this:

```
{
  "U1": 224,
  "U2": 227,
  "U3": 224,
  "I1": 0,
  "I2": 0,
  "I3": 0,
  "P": 0,
  "PF": 0,
  "E pres": 639,
  "E total": 69901578,
  "Serial": "16889379",
  "Sec": 393833
}
```

Actually I really only need to get values U1, U2, U3 and I1, I2, I3. I'm grateful for all the help I can get solving this!

Best regards
Per

Comment: Have you tried iterating over the string?

Answer (score 1):

Two possible approaches:

1. Tokenize the string using [`strtok()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/), probably a few levels deep. 
   This may require you learning quite a bit more about C++, pointers, and character arrays as strings.
2. An excellent opportunity to use an existing library, such as [ArduinoJSON](https://bblanchon.github.io/ArduinoJson/), which abstracts out the difficulties you may encounter if the fields in your JSON string arrive in a different order, etc.

An example of using ArduinoJSON for your case is shown in the documentation (excerpted/adapted from [Decoding JSON](https://bblanchon.github.io/ArduinoJson/doc/decoding/))

```
#include <ArduinoJson.h>

// [...] other code

char json[] = "{ \"U1\": 224, \"U2\": 227, \"U3\": 224, \"I1\": 0, \"I2\": 0, \"I3\": 0, \"P\": 0, \"PF\": 0, \"E pres\": 639, \"E total\": 69901578, \"Serial\": "16889379", \"Sec\": 393833 }";

//
// Step 1: Reserve memory space
//
StaticJsonBuffer<200> jsonBuffer;

//
// Step 2: Deserialize the JSON string
//
JsonObject& root = jsonBuffer.parseObject(json);

if (!root.success())
{
  Serial.println("parseObject() failed");
  return;
}

//
// Step 3: Retrieve the values
//
uint16_t    u1 = root["U1"];
uint16_t    u2 = root["U2"];
uint16_t    u3 = root["U3"];
uint16_t    i1 = root["I1"];
uint16_t    i2 = root["I2"];
uint16_t    i3 = root["I3"];
```